# Album Art now visible in Android 11

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-glide, albumart

My android application works fine till Android 9 but is failing to show thumbnails for music files in Android 11.

In the logs I'm receiving *UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown or unsupported URL* error message  with the value of thumbnail uri as `content://media/external/audio/albumart/-1850834839` & `content://media/external/audio/albumart/1937535873`.

Code Pointer :

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(audioData.getAlbumArtUri()).asBitmap()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_tile_music_browse)
        .transform(new BlurTransformation(mContext)).into(viewHolder.blurredImage);
Glide.with(mContext).load(audioData.getAlbumArtUri()).into(viewHolder.image);
```

I checked & found there have been multiple changes introduced between Android 9 & 11. Some of them are :

1. Introduction of Scoped Storage from Android 10 : Now App's can't directly access external files without having necessary permissions like `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files). Although developers can exempt from this by setting `preserveLegacyExternalStorage` to true in manifest [file](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases)
2. `album_art` has been depreciated from Android 29 & one should use `loadThumbnail` [api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns#ALBUM_ART) instead
3. I was using Glide & found there were some issue seen with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/5268) itself

I tried above resolutions but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the reason for the strange behaviour seen for my application in Android 11.

So, I tried printing the values of music albums stored in the database/MediaStore using

```
adb shell content query --uri "content://media/external/audio/media"
```

And I found the value of *album_id* field is too small (like 2,4,18) on Android 9 but while printing same data on android 11 the value was too large & could be stored by a *int* data type. Hence, the value was getting overflown resulting in negative values of album_id (-1850834839) as mentioned in the question. So, I modified the variable data type from int to long & it resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Life saving. Spent 2 hours without luck and came across this and solved my issue in a minute!